# Symfony2 unique token generator

Tags: php, mysql, forms, symfony, token

I'm developing a website and I need a way to create a token when the form is submitted to MySQL, it needs to be unique, like the ID column.

For example, when I submit the form, it inserts to DB the form data plus `Token = TXXXXXX` or whatever, actually, the format will depend on some stuff, but I think I can handle it by myself, I only need the way to create that unique token inside DB...

Does anyone knows a good way to do so?

I've tried to generate a `random` php function to generate a number, then check against MySQL, if the number exists, generate another one until I got a non-used one, then submit... Which is slow, and obviously it is **not** the best way...

Comment: Care to tell us what you've tried yourself, before pinning your hopes on a free code generator?

Comment: Updated with your request

Comment: If your table has a decent primary key specified, you could create your token like so: `md5($val1.$val2);` where `$val1` and `$val2` are the values that make up the primary key. If you're going to be adding tons of data to that db, and you're weary of `md5` causing hash collisions, use `sha1` or higher

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can use [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/uniqid), which will generate an unique id

Comment: From the doc: This function does not generate cryptographically secure tokens, in fact without being passed any additional parameters the return value is little different from `microtime()`. If you need to generate cryptographically secure tokens use `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`. http://php.net/uniqid

Answer (score 2):

There is also a function within the JMSSecurityExtraBundle which might be helpful.
see the docu: http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSecurityExtraBundle/master/random_number_generator

Answer (score 2):

I use this function to generate a random token:

```
public static function random($length = 16)
{
    if (function_exists('openssl_random_pseudo_bytes'))
    {
        $bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length * 2);

        if ($bytes === false)
        {
            // throw exception that unable to create random token
        }

        return substr(str_replace(array('/', '+', '='), '', base64_encode($bytes)), 0, $length);
    }

    return ;
}
```

The Integer Parameter you can pass to the function will determine the tokens length. Defaults to 16.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can join the current linux timestamp and the user's session-id to get a unique-id.

Answer (score 1):

With Symfony 2.3 you have a class Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Util\SecureRandom (https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Util/SecureRandom.php)